# Not running RabbitMQ on Linux, can not find the file asn1.app

Tags: centos, rabbitmq, erlang

I installed on CentOs successfully ever. However, here is another CentOs I used, and it failed to stared rabbitMq.

My erlang from here.

```
[rabbitmq-erlang]
name=rabbitmq-erlang
baseurl=https://dl.bintray.com/rabbitmq/rpm/erlang/20/el/7
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://dl.bintray.com/rabbitmq/Keys/rabbitmq-release-signing-key.asc
repo_gpgcheck=0
enabled=1
```

this is my erl_crash.dump.

```
erl_crash_dump:0.5
Sat Jun 23 09:17:30 2018
Slogan: init terminating in do_boot ({error,{no such file or directory,asn1.app}})
System version: Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.3.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:24:24] [ds:24:24:10] [async-threads:384] [hipe] [kernel-poll:true]
Compiled: Tue Jun 19 22:25:03 2018
Taints: erl_tracer,zlib
Atoms: 14794
Calling Thread: scheduler:2
=scheduler:1
Scheduler Sleep Info Flags: SLEEPING | TSE_SLEEPING | WAITING
Scheduler Sleep Info Aux Work:
Current Port:
Run Queue Max Length: 0
Run Queue High Length: 0
Run Queue Normal Length: 0
Run Queue Low Length: 0
Run Queue Port Length: 0
Run Queue Flags: OUT_OF_WORK | HALFTIME_OUT_OF_WORK
Current Process:
=scheduler:2
Scheduler Sleep Info Flags:
Scheduler Sleep Info Aux Work: THR_PRGR_LATER_OP
Current Port:
Run Queue Max Length: 0
Run Queue High Length: 0
Run Queue Normal Length: 0
Run Queue Low Length: 0
Run Queue Port Length: 0
Run Queue Flags: OUT_OF_WORK | HALFTIME_OUT_OF_WORK | NONEMPTY | EXEC
Current Process: <0.0.0>
Current Process State: Running
Current Process Internal State: ACT_PRIO_NORMAL | USR_PRIO_NORMAL | PRQ_PRIO_NORMAL | ACTIVE | RUNNING | TRAP_EXIT | ON_HEAP_MSGQ
Current Process Program counter: 0x00007fbd81fa59c0 (init:boot_loop/2 + 64)
Current Process CP: 0x0000000000000000 (invalid)
```

how to identify this problem ? Thank you.

Comment: You may want to try installing https://centos.pkgs.org/7/puias-unsupported-x86_64/erlang-asn1-18.3.4.4-1.sdl7.x86_64.rpm.html

Comment: Howerver, Dependencies of R16B asn1 conflict with many dependencies of Erlang 20.

Comment: Can you remove R16?